# How to connect to a RDP Server from a .NET Core console app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, rdp

I'm creating a C# console app that acts as a client connecting to a RDP Server. Both the client and server are on Linux machines. The target framework is .NET Core 3.1.

After some time investigating, I see that MSTSCLib is a viable option. But the code samples I found are old and documentations are sparse.

Here is what I managed to whip up so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rdp = new MsTscAxNotSafeForScripting();

            rdp.Server = "10.0.0.1";
            rdp.UserName = "clientusername";

            rdp.Connect();
        }
```

I know that there are a lot missing in that code there so I appreciate any help or documents. How do I know if my client successfully connects to the server or not?

Comment: You can not do RDP to linux machines. Normally Linux machines are connected remotely via SSH. You might want to do research on that direction.

Comment: Hi @Chetan, I managed to do RDP to a Linux machine with xrdp (http://xrdp.org/) as the server. The client uses xfreerdp (https://www.freerdp.com/). So I think it is possible right? I chose RDP because I want to eventually stream the desktop of that server machine to the client.

Comment: This seems very unlikely to work. Where did you get the idea that "MSTSCLib is a viable option"? This is a Windows-specific COM control, and while COM support has been added to .NET and may even somewhat work on Linux by now (though I don't know if it does) it's almost certainly going to be calling out to native libraries that don't exist on Linux. If you want a cross-platform RDP implementation that works with .NET, I'm afraid you'll have to write it yourself (or at least the wrapper for code that works on Linux, like the FreeRDP you mention).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I found this repo and I thought that it could work https://github.com/mrthebunny/SimpleRDPClient. Could you please elaborate more on writing "the wrapper for code that works on Linux"? Sorry, English is not my native language and I'm not familiar with this wrapper code you mentioned.

Comment: There may well be code written already that works on both Windows and Linux; my point was that MSTSCLib isn't it, as it's only going to work on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. Are there any tutorials that you would recommend to write that wrapper code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install RemoteDesktop library. You can install it via NuGet by running following command in package manager console:

```
Install-Package RemoteDesktop
```

Here is an example to connect to RDP server using RemoteDesktop library:

```
using RemoteDesktop;

var rdp = new RemoteDesktop.RemoteDesktop();
rdp.Server = "rdp.example.com";
rdp.Username = "username";
rdp.Password = "password";

rdp.Connect();
```

To disconnect from the RDP server, call the Disconnect method:

```
rdp.Disconnect();
```

You can also use other libraries and tools like FreeRDP, RemoteDesktopConnectionManager. I hope this might be helpful.

Comment: Cant find this Nuget, is it still accessible? and if it is, please provide the link!